# Avoid jagged edges when filling in quadrilateral using OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to fill in an area identified by a quadrilateral on an image, but keep getting jagged lines after performing the filling (doesn't seem to matter whether I'm filling using an image or just all plain black). I thought it was due to anti-aliasing so am using `lineType=cv2.LINE_AA` but I can still see the jagged edges.

**Q: Is there a way to avoid these jagged edges and produce smooth straight lines?**

Below is the code that I'm using:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the mockup image
mockup = cv2.imread('mockup3.png')

# Define the quadrilateral coordinates (x, y) in clockwise order
quad_coords = np.array([
    [307.7142857142857, 239.8571428571429],
    [300.57142857142856, 875.5714285714286],
    [742.3529411764706, 875.2941176470589],
    [736.2857142857143, 239.8571428571429]
], dtype=np.float32)

# Create an empty mask to fill with the smoothed quadrilateral region
mask = np.zeros(mockup.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)

# Draw a filled smoothed quadrilateral on the mask
cv2.fillPoly(mask, [quad_coords.astype(np.int32)], (255, 255, 255), lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)

# Create a black image of the same size as the mockup
black_background = np.zeros_like(mockup)

# Overlay the black background onto the mockup using the smoothed mask
result = cv2.bitwise_and(mockup, mockup, mask=~mask)
result += cv2.bitwise_and(black_background, black_background, mask=mask)

# Save the final result
cv2.imwrite('output.png', result)
```

Input image:
[image: the input image]

Output image (problematic areas highlighted in red):
[image: the output image]

Comment: why do you use binary operations? I'm not asking for justification, I'm saying **don't** and instead use arithmetic operations. -- you are trying to draw a quad with a texture, with a perspective camera. OpenCV is not a graphics library. it's for computer vision. look into OpenGL or Direct3D or whatever's supposed to be used these days.

Answer (score 0):

Part of what Chris is getting at is that anti-aliasing is done by blurring the edges of what's being drawn. By doing this on a mask, and then doing an AND, you're getting rid of the blurry edge (bitwise AND only outputs 1 or 0). You can get a smooth edge by drawing the anti-aliased polygon directly onto the image.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the mockup image
mockup = cv2.imread('mockup.png')

# Define the quadrilateral coordinates (x, y) in clockwise order
quad_coords = np.array([
    [307.7142857142857, 239.8571428571429],
    [300.57142857142856, 875.5714285714286],
    [742.3529411764706, 875.2941176470589],
    [736.2857142857143, 239.8571428571429]
], dtype=np.float32)

# Draw a filled smoothed quadrilateral on the mask
cv2.fillPoly(mockup, [quad_coords.astype(np.int32)], (0, 0, 0), lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)

# Save the final result
cv2.imwrite('output.png', result)
```

If you're looking to replace the frame with an image, you can still draw the mask like how you did, but you can't use a binary operation to overlay the mask. You want a weighted alpha blend (these are the arithmetic operations)

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the mockup image
mockup = cv2.imread('image.jpg')

# Define the quadrilateral coordinates (x, y) in clockwise order
quad_coords = np.array([
    [307.7142857142857, 239.8571428571429],
    [300.57142857142856, 875.5714285714286],
    [742.3529411764706, 875.2941176470589],
    [736.2857142857143, 239.8571428571429]
], dtype=np.float32)

# replacement image
replace = cv2.imread("tree.png") # same size as mockup.png

# Create an empty mask to fill with the smoothed quadrilateral region
mask = np.zeros_like(mockup, dtype=np.uint8)

# Draw a filled smoothed quadrilateral on the mask
cv2.fillPoly(mask, [quad_coords.astype(np.int32)], (255,255,255), lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
mask = mask.astype(np.float32) / 255.0

# overlay alpha on both (invert for mockup)
mockup = mockup.astype(np.float32) / 255.0
mockup = cv2.multiply(1.0 - mask, mockup)

replace = replace.astype(np.float32) / 255.0
replace = cv2.multiply(mask, replace)

# mix together
mockup = cv2.add(mockup, replace)

# convert back to uint8
mockup = (mockup * 255.0).astype(np.uint8)

# Save the final result
cv2.imwrite('output.png', mockup)
cv2.imshow("Output", mockup);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

[image]